# Can I get beacons data in Exit Regions also how can I detect when new beacon enterered into the region?

Tags: android, altbeacon

When multiple beacons are detected in the regions,

how can I find that which one is the newest detected one?

Also in beacon exist how can I know that specific beacon has left the region.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to solve this is to **combine beacon monitoring and beacon ranging**.

You use beacon ranging to read the individual identifiers, and keep a map of what beacons have been seen before like this:

```
private HashSet<Beacon> beaconsSeen = new HashSet<Beacon>();
@Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {]
    for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
        if (!beaconsSeen.contains(beacon)) {
            beaconsSeen.add(beacon);
            // Perform your logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Since you want the logic to trigger again if the beacon is later rediscovered after all beacons in the region disappear, you must clear the map on region exit:

```
@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    beaconsSeen.clear();
}
```

Comment: great @davidgyoung, but I want in didExitRegion method it remove not all beacon data but only that one beacon which is out if range, other beacon's are still in HashSet

Comment: When didExitRegion is called, that means *all* beacons in the region have disappeared.