# How to find the UUID or Mac address of a beacon when enter or exit a region using andriod beacon library.?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

```
@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region)
{
    Log.d("EXITED",region.getUniqueId());
    sendNotification("Exited");
    sendNotification("time exited is"+timer());
    String s1 = region.getBluetoothAddress();
    sendNotification("mac" +s1);

}
```

tried using the getBluetoothAddress but always showing null.
Aim: I want to send the notification which contains the MAC address or UUID of the beacon upon exiting the region?

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849297/can-i-get-beacons-data-in-exit-regions-also-how-can-i-detect-when-new-beacon-ent/39862717#39862717

Comment: private HashSet<Beacon> beaconsSeen = new HashSet<Beacon>();
@Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {]
    for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
        if (!beaconsSeen.contains(beacon)) {
            beaconsSeen.add(beacon);
            // Perform your logic here
        }
    }
}

Comment: But I tried that still I am not able to get the Bluetooth address of the beacons. As I am new to BLE and java I am finding it hard can you please specify how can I modify the method to get the mac address of the beacon upon entering into the region.